# pig cql not working with greater/lesser than condition

Tags: cassandra, apache-pig

I am using pig 0.11.1 with cassandra 1.2.12, when i write a pig cql like

**PK for "employees" is ((date,id),joindatems)**

> data = LOAD
>   'cql://company/employees?where_clause=+joindatems+%3C+1388769238536746+and+joindatems+%3E+1388768338536746'
>   using CqlStorage();

Its joindatems is datetime in milliseconds, here am having a condition **joindatems < 1388769238536746 and joindatems > 1388768338536746**
when i run this am getting

```
Caused by: InvalidRequestException(why:joindatems  cannot be restricted by both an equal and an inequal relation)
```

but this this kind of query(joindatems < 1388769238536746 and joindatems > 1388768338536746) is supported in cassandra cql, am i doing anything wrong in pig script.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure if it will help, but as a workaround: perhaps you can apply two filters after the load instead?